# Why `&(&i32, &i32)` is matched identically against the closures `|&(&x, &y)|` and `|(&x, &y)|`?

Tags: rust

Let's consider the following snippet:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![10, -1, 2];
    let b = vec![-1, 10, 2];
    assert_eq!(
        a.iter()
        .zip(b.iter())
        // .filter(|&(&x, &y)| x > 0 && y > 0) // (A)
        // .filter(|(&x, &y)| x > 0 && y > 0) // (B)
        .map(|(a, b)| a + b)
        .max()
        .unwrap(),
        4
    );
}
```

The commented lines `(A)` and `(B)` are two ways to keep only pairs with both elements being positive. `(A)` follows the input's signature (which is `&(&i32, &i32)`), hence, both `x` and `y` are inferred as `i32` and the line is successfully compiled, no questions about that. However, in `(B)`, both `x` and `y` are also inferred as `i32` even though there is just one `&`. Why does `(B)` works this way even though it looks different from `(A)`?

Comment: The reason that both ways work is because the compiler is able to infer the types of both x and y in both cases. In (A), the types are inferred from the signature of the input, which is &(&i32, &i32). In (B), the types are inferred from the context in which the closures are used. In both cases, the compiler is able to correctly infer that both x and y are of type i32.

Comment: Rust didn't always behave like this. This was added in 2017 under the feature name "match ergonomics". You can find out more in the [RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html), but the change essentially made it so you didn't have to think so much about references when writing patterns, and the compiler would work out what you meant, without having to be too explicit.